# jQuery custom content scroller unable to save position

Tags: php, jquery, scroll

I have a question about jQuery custom content scroller.

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

When I hide and show this scroller with jQuery `$("id").hide();` and `$("id").show();`, it moves the scroll position to the top. Can I preserve the scroll position so it does not move?

Comment: share the code what you have tried also share the screenshot of output what you get

Comment: Create fiddle what you have done so far

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this,

var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(scroll);

$("html").scrollTop(scroll);